# Angular rxjs: multiple dependent rest calls, display when 1st is completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

Racking my brains on this one:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.hotel$ = getHotel(<enteredid>); // first rest call 
    this.hotelrooms$ = this.hotel$.pipe(switchMap(hotel => getHotelRooms(hotel))); // second rest call
    this.occupancy$ = combineLatest([this.hotel$, this.hotelrooms$])
      .pipe(switchMap(([hotel, rooms]) => getOccupancy(hotel, rooms)));
    this.roomsWithOccupancy$ = combineLatest([this.hotelrooms$, this.occupancy$])
      .pipe(switchMap(([hotel, rooms]) => mergeRoomsWithOccupancy(hotel, rooms)));
  }
```

The problem is that getOccupancy is slow (external service) > 20s and I want to show the hotels and rooms already before it comes back.

I see several options:

1. I can do another combineLatest of hotelRooms and occupancy, but then it will wait for both to return
2. I can display hotelRooms first but how do I merge in the occupancy data (both are arrays) in the component?
3. Is there an operator similar to combineLatest that will return when hotelRooms is there and emit again when the occupancies are there?
4. Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use merge instead of combine latest, one will emit, then the other. You will have to test the emitted value to see what data type was returned.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hotel$ = getHotel(<enteredid>); // first rest call 
    this.hotelrooms$ = this.hotel$.pipe(switchMap(hotel => getHotelRooms(hotel))); // second rest call
    this.occupancy$ = merge(this.hotel$, this.hotelrooms$)
      .pipe(switchMap((result) => test result));
  }
```

Comment: I edited the original pseudo code: it was actually the next line I was looking for a solution to. My problem with merge is that parameter to the operator after the merge will then be a HotelRooms[] | Occupancy[]. How do I merge the data if I only ever have one or the other.

Comment: If you need both then you need to use combine latest

Comment: Yes but back to my original problem: combineLatest will wait for at least one value to be emitted from both. Which means that the display will happen only after around 20s.